# Elegant summation of list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

List comprehensions are great. Is there an elegant, slick way to do a list comprehension that *appends* items to each other as they go, rather than putting them all in a list?

IE, I have some comprehension `[func(x) for x in y if z]` that spits out `[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]`, what can i write to instead spit out `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`?

Obviously I could do

```
alist = []

for x in y:
    if z:
        alist += func(x)
```

but that's four or five lines of code! it feels like there must be a way to do it that's as simple and easy as the list comprehension is.

Comment: Related [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[elem for x in y if z for elem in func(x)]
```

Just add another layer of iteration.

Comment: [Here](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) is a useful resource for understanding multi-layered list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't specific to list comprehensions; it has to do with flattening of nested containers or iterables in general. (That would include, `list`, `tuple`, `set`, etc.)

Unlike some sloppier programming languages — *cough* whose names also start with “P” *cough* — Python never *implicitly* flattens nested containers.

The standard-library Pythonic way to flatten a nested container is with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), which works as a generator and thus avoids making unnecessary intermediary copies of the list, or whatever iterable you pass it. There are two ways to invoke it:

- `chain(iterable1, iterable2, …)`: for example, `list(chain([1,2],[3,4]))` → `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- `chain.from_iterable(iterable_of_iterables)`: for example, `l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; list(chain.from_iterable(l))` → `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

For your specific example:

```py
from itertools import chain

# Your starting case:
l = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]

# This is now an iterator, not a list
it = chain.from_iterable(l)

# Make it back into a list
l2 = list(it)

# Prints:
#   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print(l2)
```